# Upgrade ScriptSharp from 0.7.4 to 0.7.6 throws "getField is not defined" errors

Tags: script#

I just compiled the master branch of ScriptSharp on my machine and upgraded the dlls (mscorlib, Script.jQuery, Script.jQuery.History, Script.Web) and javascript (mscorlib.js) files of my project.

I had to change a lot of `Type.GetField`, `Type.SetField` and `Type.InvokeMethod` calls to use them in the Script class because they were moved there in 0.7.6. Then my project compiled successfully.

Now, when I load my project in the browser, I have this `getField is not defined` error. I tested on Windows 7 in Chrome and Internet Explorer 10 and got the same error in both. I also checked that the `mscorlib.js` file my browser is using is the 0.7.6 one.

Did I miss something? Where this `getField` method is supposed to be declared? I don't see it in `mscorlib.js`.

Thank you

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you also update the compiler from your private build? Specifically the ScriptSharp.dll and ScriptSharp.Build assemblies. As well as the msbuild .targets file that matches those.

The new compiler that goes hand-in-hand should also convert Script.GetField into the desired script, rather than a call to a non-existant getField method.

Comment: I built all the ScriptSharp solution of my private ScriptSharp build. ScriptSharp.dll and ScriptSharp.Build.dll were built at that time.

However, I forgot to change the ScriptSharp.targets file used by my script project to use the 0.7.6 one. It was compiled with the 0.7.4 one and that's what caused the issue. Thanks!